# Updating dependencies not working

Tags: go, ubuntu-16.04

I'm following golang.org installation to install go 1.10

```
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/Descargas$ sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.10.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz 
[sudo] password for delia: 
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/Descargas$ sudo nano ~/.profile 
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/Descargas$ source ~/.profile 
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/Descargas$ go version
go version go1.10.2 linux/amd64
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/Descargas$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/delia/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/delia/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build260040487=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Adding in ~/.profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Now I download some code from github and when I try to run go get -t -u ./...

```
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/Descargas$ sudo git clone https://www.github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go
Clonar en «quic-go»...
remote: Counting objects: 16080, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
remote: Total 16080 (delta 4), reused 6 (delta 1), pack-reused 16063
Receiving objects: 100% (16080/16080), 5.25 MiB | 2.79 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (12239/12239), done.
Comprobando la conectividad… hecho.
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/Descargas$ cd quic-go/
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/Descargas/quic-go$ go get -t -u ./...
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/benchmark: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/benchmark" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/example: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/example" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/example/client: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/example/client" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/example/echo: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/example/echo" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/h2quic: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/h2quic" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/integrationtests/chrome: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/integrationtests/chrome" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/integrationtests/gquic: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/integrationtests/gquic" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/integrationtests/self: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/integrationtests/self" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/proxy: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/proxy" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testlog: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testlog" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testserver: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testserver" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/ackhandler: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/ackhandler" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/congestion: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/congestion" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/crypto: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/crypto" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/flowcontrol: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/flowcontrol" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/handshake: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/handshake" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/mocks: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/mocks" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/mocks/ackhandler: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/mocks/ackhandler" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/mocks/crypto: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/mocks/crypto" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/mocks/handshake: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/mocks/handshake" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/protocol: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/protocol" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/utils: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/utils" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/utils/linkedlist: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/utils/linkedlist" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/wire: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/internal/wire" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/qerr: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/Descargas/quic-go/qerr" (import path does not begin with hostname)
```

Everyone says this problem comes with a bad installation of go. But I'm following golang instructions for Ubuntu 16.04 64bits. So, I don't know where is it the problem

EDIT:

I tried the same in $GOPATH:

```
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/go$ cd $GOPATH
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/go$ pwd
/home/delia/go
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/go$ sudo git clone https://www.github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go
Clonar en «quic-go»...
remote: Counting objects: 16080, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
remote: Total 16080 (delta 4), reused 6 (delta 1), pack-reused 16063
Receiving objects: 100% (16080/16080), 5.25 MiB | 1020.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (12239/12239), done.
Comprobando la conectividad… hecho.
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/go$ go get -t -u ./...
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/benchmark: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/benchmark" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/example: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/example" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/example/client: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/example/client" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/example/echo: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/example/echo" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/h2quic: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/h2quic" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/chrome: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/chrome" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/gquic: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/gquic" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/self: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/self" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/proxy: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/proxy" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testlog: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testlog" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testserver: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testserver" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/ackhandler: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/ackhandler" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/congestion: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/congestion" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/crypto: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/crypto" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/flowcontrol: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/flowcontrol" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/handshake: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/handshake" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks/ackhandler: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks/ackhandler" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks/crypto: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks/crypto" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks/handshake: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks/handshake" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/protocol: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/protocol" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/utils: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/utils" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/utils/linkedlist: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/utils/linkedlist" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/wire: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/wire" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/qerr: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/qerr" (import path does not begin with hostname)
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/go$ cd quic-go/
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/go/quic-go$ go get -t -u ./...
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/benchmark: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/benchmark" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/example: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/example" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/example/client: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/example/client" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/example/echo: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/example/echo" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/h2quic: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/h2quic" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/chrome: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/chrome" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/gquic: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/gquic" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/self: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/self" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/proxy: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/proxy" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testlog: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testlog" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testserver: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testserver" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/ackhandler: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/ackhandler" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/congestion: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/congestion" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/crypto: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/crypto" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/flowcontrol: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/flowcontrol" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/handshake: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/handshake" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks/ackhandler: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks/ackhandler" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks/crypto: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks/crypto" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks/handshake: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/mocks/handshake" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/protocol: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/protocol" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/utils: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/utils" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/utils/linkedlist: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/utils/linkedlist" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/wire: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/internal/wire" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package _/home/delia/go/quic-go/qerr: unrecognized import path "_/home/delia/go/quic-go/qerr" (import path does not begin with hostname)
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/go/quic-go$
```

Edit 2:

I tried the same in $GOPATH/src:

```
delia@delia-VirtualBox:~/go/src/quic-go$ go get -t -u ./...
# cd /home/delia/go/src/quic-go; git pull --ff-only
fatal: index file smaller than expected
package quic-go: exit status 128
package quic-go/benchmark: 
benchmark/benchmark_suite_test.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/example: 
example/main.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/example/client: 
example/client/main.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/example/echo: 
example/echo/echo.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/h2quic: 
h2quic/client.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/integrationtests/chrome: 
integrationtests/chrome/chrome_suite_test.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/integrationtests/gquic: 
integrationtests/gquic/drop_test.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/integrationtests/self: 
integrationtests/self/client_test.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/integrationtests/tools/proxy: 
integrationtests/tools/proxy/proxy.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testlog: 
integrationtests/tools/testlog/testlog.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/integrationtests/tools/testserver: 
integrationtests/tools/testserver/server.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/internal/ackhandler: 
internal/ackhandler/ackhandler_suite_test.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/internal/congestion: 
internal/congestion/bandwidth.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/internal/crypto: 
internal/crypto/AEAD.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/internal/flowcontrol: 
internal/flowcontrol/base_flow_controller.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/internal/handshake: 
internal/handshake/cookie_generator.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/internal/mocks: 
internal/mocks/congestion.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/internal/mocks/ackhandler: 
internal/mocks/ackhandler/received_packet_handler.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/internal/mocks/crypto: 
internal/mocks/crypto/aead.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/internal/mocks/handshake: 
internal/mocks/handshake/mint_tls.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/internal/protocol: 
internal/protocol/connection_id.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/internal/utils: 
internal/utils/atomic_bool.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/internal/utils/linkedlist: 
internal/utils/linkedlist/linkedlist.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/internal/wire: 
internal/wire/ack_frame.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
package quic-go/qerr: 
qerr/error_codes.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
```

Comment: Don't follow the Ubuntu installation instructions. Follow the [official installation instructions](https://golang.org/doc/install).

Comment: You need to `sudo git clone` the project into `$GOPATH`, not `~/Descargas/`. Running `go get -t -u ./...` from outside of the `$GOPATH` will just not work.

Comment: Same problem (you can see the edit)

Comment: @delinage source needs to be in the `src` directory of `$GOPATH`. So to correct my previous comment, your Go projects need to live in `$GOPATH/src`.

Comment: @delinage to understand why, please read [this short article](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces) on how to organize your projects withing the go workspace.

Comment: @mkopriva mmm ok, I tried it and now the error changed... (edit 2) I would suppose it's some kind of problem with the code but the code is not mine, it is a code that works, so... the problem is still with go

Comment: @delinage Please read the article about the Go workspaces and how the projects should be organized inside `$GOPATH`. The import paths in the source must match the package locations relative from `$GOPATH/src`. That means that the quic-go project should live in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go`. Instead of doing `git clone` you should just do `go get github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go` , this will pull the project into `$GOPATH/src/github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go` automatically.

Comment: ... you can use `git clone <go-project> <into-any-directory>` only if you don't intend to actually build and run the go project, only if you intend to maybe just work on the source. In cases where you want to work on the source but also want to build and run the project you should use `go get <go-project-repo>` to save yourself the headache.

Comment: @mkopriva Now I understand! (and it works) Thank you so much!